# PyQt toolbar in 2nd row by default

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm adding a simple toolbar to my PyQt application and trying to get the toolbar to start by default in the top position, but in the 2nd row beneath another toolbar.

I have called:

`self.addToolBar(Qt.TopToolBarArea, navBar)`

This combines the toolbar with my first toolbar which is much shorter into the same row.  Is there a way to force these toolbars to be in separate rows?

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the solution after scouring the documentation and trying different options.  I think I was looking for something along the lines of "toolBarRow" so I missed it.

The solution is to insert a `toolBarBreak`.  The same way a separator can be added to a toolbar itself, a "break" simply breaks up one of the four areas provided for tool bars: either top, bottom, left, or right.  It is added with similar functions to the way separators are added to toolbars, with:

`QMainWindow.addToolBarBreak()` which adds to the "end" of the toolbar area, which really means the most inward position.

or

`QMainWindow.insertToolBarBreak(toolBarBefore)` which adds right before the passed in toolbar reference.